# How to spawn villagers in an nearly empty village?

Tags: minecraft-education-edition

I have this village that WAS empty but recently spawned only ONE villager.

Is there a way I could repopulate the village?

Like a villager mob spawner?

Comment: Just to confirm, this tag is correct and we're talking about MC Education Edition, not Java or Bedrock?

Comment: YEP I use MC ED @MikeG

Comment: You must have at least two vilagers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to find zombie villagers and cure them.

Zombie villagers are curable by throwing a splash potion of weakness at them, then giving them a golden apple (by using similar button controls that feeding animals uses).

If you've done this successfully, a loud crackling sound effect would play and the curing process starts; the zombie villager will have red potion particles, they'll begin to start shaking violently, and they'll have stronger attack damage so make sure that they're confined to a space.

It will take a couple minutes for the curing process to complete (though confining curing zombie villagers around iron bars slightly decreases the time wait), and when it's finished the zombie villager will have turned into a regular villager.

Once you have two villagers in your village population then you could choose to start doing traditional villager breeders, and you choose to continue curing other zombie villagers if you have the resources for it.

Comment: However, if you're looking for a way to spontaneously spawn in villagers without the processes of breeding or curing, then you could also try the /summon command on a cheats-enabled world to spawn a villager in a specific set of coordinates, and with command blocks (obtained by typing /give @s command_block), you could automate this villager summoning process given the right set-up.

Comment: Look the village was empty when I first spawned. Then one day, it just spawned a villager without me wondering. I was wondering how I could replicate that same process. @BlueTangsRock

Comment: Ah, Understood.     Are you sure that it wasn't a wandering trader, rather than a regular villager?   I'm just trying to have a good understanding of the situation.

Comment: It was a villager. He was brown colored not blue

Answer (score 0):

If you have two villagers, trap them somewhere in a building that they cannot get out of and place doors everywhere inside the building. Also, place down beds inside the building and if there's two villagers, they will breed. But idk if you're gonna be able to do it without two villagers, try placing down several beds first to spawn a second villager. If you're in creative mode,(which you're probably not) use a villager spawn egg, found in the miscellaneous section. That's all I have.

Edit: you could place beds inside the villager homes.

Comment: Hmm could you edit your post to show me an example of a way to spawn that second villager? @Korogue

Comment: also bluetangrock gave another way to get new villagers.

Comment: They need food as well, so if the 2 villagers don’t have any in their inventory, they probably won’t breed.